# Upgrade rails 2.3.8 project to rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created a  project using rails 2.3.8..  Now i need to move rails 3.x.x ..so how can i upgrade my project also?
please tell some tutorial or link to upgrade this?

Comment: Try searching Google or Stack Overflow before asking - http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=upgrade+rails+2+to+rails+3

Answer (score 2):

Start by using the [rails upgrade gem](http://omgbloglol.com/post/364624593/rails-upgrade-is-now-an-official-plugin). There are several tutorials out on the web that can walk you through what you need to do.

Most importantly, TEST your app thoroughly after doing so.

Comment: RAILS 3 UPGRADE HANDBOOK PDF

http://peepcode.com/products/rails-3-upgrade-handbook-pdf it's not free, but 120 pages...

Comment: @house9, Forgot about that, well worth it!